# AsciiDoc viewer for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, software-recommendation

Is there an AsciiDoc viewer for Mac OS X? Preferably one that views the document live, much like MacDown for markdown documents.

There’s nothing on the App Store, and I’ve done rounds of the search engines.

I would prefer a solution without Java if that's possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Google Chrome browser can render AsciiDoc files.  Just open an AsciiDoc file from Google Chrome using the menu item File -> Open File or the keyboard shortcut Cmd-O, and you should see the "live" file.

(Edit: I forgot that this requires the Asciidoctor.js Live Preview extension for Chrome).

In your editor, when you make changes and save the file, Chrome will automatically update its view.

Also, some editors (e.g. Atom - see https://atom.io) also have plugins that do live previews.

Comment: I didn’t know about either of those. I also note that there is an addon for Firefox and for Brackets. That will be a huge help. Thanks.

Comment: Anything for Safari? I do keep Chrome around, but my default way to roll is Safari. Edit: I tried that plugin, but it didn't render the asciidoc file in any other way than a text editor would.

Comment: Nothing for Safari afaik.   So Asciidoctor.js Live Preview installed in Chrome didn't render the document?   Maybe something is misconfigured in the extension (e.g. permissions)?  BTW, check out http://asciidocfx.com, a "book editor" for Asciidoc-based documents (it's Java-based, so it doesn't address the OP's question).

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

I have since then found the following additional solutions:

- [Atom](https://atom.io/) with [asciidoc-preview](https://atom.io/packages/asciidoc-preview)
- [Marked 2 - Smarter tools for smarter writers](http://marked2app.com/) (Get the non-AppStore version for technical reasons).
- [GitBook Editor](https://www.gitbook.com/editor)

In the first 2 cases, you will also need to install **asciidoctor**.

**Atom** is my preferred every-day solution, as it uses a split window and updates automatically.

**Marked 2** simply watches and automatically previews a text document which you edit in any other text editor. Getting it to work with asciidoc requires a few extra steps, and the App Store version gets in the way.

**GitBook Editor** should be the most satisfactory. I has gone through a few disruptive version changes, but is mostly working again. My main problems with it are that there are no line numbers, which makes editing long documents a bit of a pain, and you have no control over the styling.

It is designed to work with a free or paid `GitBook` account, but it is free, and you don’t need use one.

Answer (score 0):

If you already use any of the JetBrains IntelliJ IDEs (I wouldn't recommend installing them just for this purpose) then there is an AsciiDoc plugin available.

Open an AsciiDoc from File->Open menu, it will show the plain text.

Top right it should indicate a plugin is available, click on the link and install the plugin.

Bottom right it should suggest for you to restart the IDE to make the plugin active. Click "Restart" and wait for IDE to restart.

You will get a dual-pane view (text plus preview) of the doc, like this:

[image]

And at the top of this pane you have some controls, among them the ability to view just the raw text, both, or just the preview.